# Table has sql statements in each row. How do I run each in order?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using `Microsoft SQL Server`. I have a table in my database. The first line is an `Item #` in numerical order and second column is exact lines of `T-SQL` that I need to run.

How do I write something that calls each line to run in the order of the item number?

```
 Item #       Code
 ------       ----
   1          UPDATE GOC_AU_INTERSECTION SET GOC_AU_INTERSECTION.DSMT_BUSINESS = 'BUSA',
              GOC_AU_INTERSECTION.RULE_CODE = '101'  FROM DSMT_GOC_FLAT, GOC_AU_INTERSECTION                     
              WHERE GOC_AU_INTERSECTION.RULE_CODE Is Null AND DSMT_GOC_FLAT.MS_Level_10='14197'           
              AND DSMT_GOC_FLAT.GOC = GOC_AU_INTERSECTION.GOC;  

   2          UPDATE GOC_AU_INTERSECTION SET GOC_AU_INTERSECTION.DSMT_BUSINESS = 'BUSA',           
              GOC_AU_INTERSECTION.RULE_CODE = '102' FROM DSMT_GOC_FLAT, GOC_AU_INTERSECTION            
              WHERE GOC_AU_INTERSECTION.RULE_CODE Is Null AND DSMT_GOC_FLAT.MS_Level_10='14198'             
              AND DSMT_GOC_FLAT.GOC = GOC_AU_INTERSECTION.GOC;     

   3          UPDATE GOC_AU_INTERSECTION SET GOC_AU_INTERSECTION.DSMT_BUSINESS = 'BUSA', 
              GOC_AU_INTERSECTION.RULE_CODE = '103' FROM DSMT_GOC_FLAT, GOC_AU_INTERSECTION 
              WHERE GOC_AU_INTERSECTION.RULE_CODE Is Null AND DSMT_GOC_FLAT.MS_Level_10='14202' 
              AND DSMT_GOC_FLAT.GOC = GOC_AU_INTERSECTION.GOC ;
```

Comment: since you are new, just a reminder it is important that if an answer answers your question to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a cursor and `sp_executesql`

```
DECLARE @sqlStmt VARCHAR(4000);

DECLARE exCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT Column2 FROM table ORDER BY Column1;

OPEN exCursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM exCursor INTO @sqlStmt;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlStmt;

    FETCH NEXT FROM exCursor INTO @sqlStmt;
END

CLOSE exCursor;
DEALLOCATE exCursor;
```

The cursor will be created to query from your statement table and retrieve your sql statements, ordering by column1.  You then get each statement and execute it.

**Read More about it**

- [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)
- [DECLARE CURSOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx)

Another thing about `sp_executesql` is that you can pass parameters too it.  I noticed your statement in quite repetitive - you could have one table with queries and one with parameters.  Could be a good idea if this is a long term solution.

Answer (score 1):

I hate `CURSORS`, so I would offer you do build a dynamic SQL statement and then execute it.
This is full working example:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

    DECLARE @Statement TABLE
    (
        [Item #] TINYINT IDENTITY(1,1)
       ,[Code] NVARCHAR(32)
    )

    INSERT INTO @Statement ([Code])
    VALUES ('SELECT 1')
          ,('SELECT 2')
          ,('SELECT 3')

    DECLARE @DynamicSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @DynamicSQLStatement =
    (
        SELECT CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + [Code] + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13)
        FROM @Statement
        ORDER BY [Item #]
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')

    --SELECT @DynamicSQLStatement

    EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicSQLStatement


SET NOCOUNT OFF
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is

```
  declare @sql nvarchar(max)=''
  select @sql+= Code+' ' from tablename order by Item#
  exec sp_executesql  @sql
```

@DanielGimenez += is a valid TSQL operator. check this

```
DECLARE @string varchar(10) = 'abc'

SET @string += 'def'

print @string
```